# Table Tree Structure in html using Json?

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a JSON, from which i need to form a tree structure and also i have search box where i will enter a text it will search from the json and show me the list.
My Json

> {"profile":"CM_MGR","resources":{"LEASE":{"id":"LEASE","name":"LEASE","type":"MODULE","child":{"CLINE":{"id":"CLINE","name":"CREDIT
>   LINE","type":"MENU","child":{"RR":{"id":"RR","name":"RISK
>   RATING","type":"SUB_MENU"},"CMTS":{"id":"CMTS","name":"COMMENTS","type":"SUB_MENU","action":4},"FIN":{"id":"FIN","name":"FINANCE","type":"SUB_MENU","action":5},"FA":{"id":"FA","name":"FINANCIAL
>   ANALYSIS","type":"SUB_MENU","action":16},"CCL":{"id":"CCL","name":"CREATE
>   CREDIT
>   LINE","type":"SUB_MENU","action":5}},"action":2},"CUST":{"id":"CUST","name":"CUSTOMER","type":"MENU","child":{"EASSET":{"id":"EASSET","name":"EXISTING
>   ASSET","type":"SUB_MENU","action":1},"MGMT":{"id":"MGMT","name":"MANAGEMENT","type":"SUB_MENU","action":1},"BMODEL":{"id":"BMODEL","name":"BUSINESS
>   MODEL","type":"SUB_MENU","action":16},"DEMO":{"id":"DEMO","name":"DEMOGRAPHICS","type":"SUB_MENU","child":{"IDEN":{"id":"IDEN","name":"IDENTIFICATION
>   DETIALS","type":"PAGE"},"CLASS":{"id":"CLASS","name":"CLASSIFICATION","type":"PAGE"},"CPERS":{"id":"CPERS","name":"CONTACT
>   PERSON","type":"PAGE"},"BDATA":{"id":"BDATA","name":"BASIC
>   DATA","type":"PAGE"},"ADDR":{"id":"ADDR","name":"ADDRESS","type":"PAGE"}}}},"action":2},"LI":{"id":"LI","name":"LEASE
>   INITIATION","type":"MENU","child":{"CF":{"id":"CF","name":"CASH
>   FLOW","type":"SUB_MENU","action":4},"BASSET":{"id":"BASSET","name":"BASIC
>   ASSET
>   DETAILS","type":"SUB_MENU","action":16},"LQ":{"id":"LQ","name":"LEASE
>   QUATATION","type":"SUB_MENU","action":16},"B\u0026A":{"id":"B\u0026A","name":"LINK
>   BUYBACK \u0026
>   ASSIGNEE","type":"SUB_MENU","action":16},"GUAR":{"id":"GUAR","name":"LINK
>   GUARANTOR","type":"SUB_MENU","action":1},"INS":{"id":"INS","name":"INSURANCE","type":"SUB_MENU"}},"action":1},"UD":{"id":"UD","name":"UNDERWRITER","type":"MENU","child":{"RRCMT":{"id":"RRCMT","name":"RISK
>   RATING
>   COMMENTS","type":"SUB_MENU","action":16},"CARPT":{"id":"CARPT","name":"CREDIT
>   APPRAISAL
>   REPORT","type":"SUB_MENU","action":13},"CLA":{"id":"CLA","name":"CREDIT
>   LINE APPROVAL","type":"SUB_MENU"},"CMEMO":{"id":"CMEMO","name":"CREDIT
>   APPROVAL
>   MEMO","type":"SUB_MENU","action":16},"AL":{"id":"AL","name":"APPROVAL
>   LETTER","type":"SUB_MENU"},"GRPT":{"id":"GRPT","name":"GUARANTOR
>   REPORT","type":"SUB_MENU","action":13},"SFA":{"id":"SFA","name":"SUBMIT
>   FOR APPROVAL","type":"SUB_MENU"},"UCL":{"id":"UCL","name":"UPDATE
>   CREDIT
>   LINE","type":"SUB_MENU","action":4}},"action":2}}},"ADMIN":{"id":"ADMIN","name":"ADMIN","type":"MODULE","child":{"USERS":{"id":"USERS","name":"USERS","type":"PAGE"}}}}}

i need to design the page with below structure. can some one help me ? i have no idea how to do that

[image]

```
 $.each(data, function(key, val) {
       /**/
        if(data["resources"] != null){
           // console.log(key);
            if(key == "resources"){
                $.each(val, function(key1, val1) {
                    // console.log(key1);
                    $.each(val1, function(key2, val2) {
                        if(key2 == "name"){
                            // console.log(key2);
                           //  console.log(JSON.stringify(val2));
                             text = $('<li>'+val2+'</li>');

                        }if(key2 == "child"){
                            $.each(val2,function(key3,val3){
                              // alert(key3);
                            // alert(JSON.stringify(val3["name"]));

                                   // console.log(val3);
                                    text1 = $('<ul><li>'+val3["name"]+'</li>');
                                   lastLine = text.append(text1);
                                   lastLine.appendTo('.tbodyResource');
                                    $.each(val3,function(key4,val4){

                                        if(key4 == "child"){

                                            $.each(val4,function(key5,val5){
                                                alert(JSON.stringify(val5));
                                                  /* text2 = $('<ul><li>'+val5["name"]+'</li></ul></ul></ul></td></tr>');
                                                    lastLine = text.append(text1);
                                                   s = lastLine.append(text2);
                                                   s.appendTo('.tbodyResource');*/
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });

                            });
                        }

                });

                });
            }

        }
       });
```

[image]

I got this as o/p, i know i was wrong in this approach

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich i have updated my code